# Mongoexport with Query using shell script

Tags: bash, mongodb

I am calling mongoexport using shell script but it keeps failing. My script is :--

```
mongo localhost:27038/admin -u test -p mongo123 < mongoexport.js
```

and my mongoexport.js file is :--

```
use db1
mongoexport --type=csv --fields _id -q '{"_id": "323549991" , "cat" : "ABC"}' --out report.csv
```

But every time I run it fails with below error :--

```
switched to db db1
2018-01-10T17:36:15.495+0000 E QUERY    [thread1] SyntaxError: missing ;   before statement @(shell):1:14 
bye
```

Now I am not sure where exactly I am messing up the syntax .

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are connecting to your mongo. You don't need to do that in order to execute `mongoexport`.
You just need to connect to your host (not mongo). Take a look at the [official documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoexport/#export-from-remote-host-running-with-authentication)

> This data resides on the MongoDB instance located on the host
>   mongodb1.example.net running on port 37017, which requires the
>   username user and the password pass.
>
> mongoexport --host mongodb1.example.net --port 37017 --username user
>   --password "pass" --collection contacts --db marketing --out mdb1-examplenet.json

In your case it should look like that (**Untested**)

```
mongoexport --host localhost --port 27038 --username test --password "mongo123" --db admin --collection db1 --type=csv --fields _id -q '{"_id": "323549991" , "cat" : "ABC"}' --out report.csv
```

I assumed your database is called admin and your collection db1, if not replace them accordingly.